# How do you use an StdGen type in the arguments?

Tags: haskell

Im creating a function with a list of Int's and an StdGen as args and randomly chooses an element from that list, and returns that element along with the new seed.

```
random_ele :: [Int] -> StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)

random_ele xs g = (xs!!r1, g1) where (r1, g1) = randomR (0, ((length xs)-1)) g
```

The input: `random_ele [1,2,3,4,5] 3456`
Produces this error: `No instance for (Num StdGen) arising from the literal ‘3456’`

Answer (score 4):

A `StdGen` isn't an integer.  (It's actually a pair of 32-bit integers, but that's an implementation detail.)  What you're looking for is the `mkStdGen :: Int -> StdGen` function which accepts an integer seed and creates a valid `StdGen`:

```
> random_ele [1,2,3,4,5] (mkStdGen 3456)
(1,138328398 40692)
```

Oh, and the meaning of the error message is that GHC can't find a `Num` instance for `StdGen` that **would** allow it to convert the literal `3456` directly to a `StdGen`, the way `3456` can be converted directly to a `Double`, `Int`, `Integer`, etc.  (because these types all have `Num` instances).  You'd get a similar error if you tried to use `3456` as a `Bool`:

```
> not 3456
error: ... No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘3456’ ...
```

Comment: Is there anyway to implement mkStdGen into the function so that the signature stays the same and `random_ele [1,2,3,4,5] 3456` works as an input?

Comment: @MattWitty If by that you mean that the `3456` is an `Int` parameter and you call `mkStdGen` within `random_ele`, then obviously you can't do it by keeping the signature the same; you'd need to take an `Int` for the second parameter instead of a `StdGen`. It also wouldn't be a good idea; you then wouldn't be able to use `random_ele` as one part in a sequence of random calculations, because it would demand an `Int` but the output of random calculations would be a new `StdGen` to use in the next one, not an `Int`.